# Using javascript/lodash to group identical values for a specific key and count them and return results to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iterator, lodash

I have a collection of objects from which I use lodash's _.map function to get all the corresponding values for a specific key:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "alarm_type": "danger",
    "data": "Dapibus ac facilisis in facilisilitumas el perfertum"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "alarm_type": "danger",
    "data": "Cras sit amet nibh libero"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "alarm_type": "warning",
    "data": "Porta ac consectetur ac"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "alarm_type": "info",
    "data": "Vestibulum at eros porta ac consectetur ac"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "alarm_type": "success",
    "data": "Morbi leo risus"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "alarm_type": "default",
    "data": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
}, {
    "id": 7,
    "alarm_type": "danger",
    "data": "Cras sit amet nibh libero"
}, {
}, {
    "id": 8,
    "alarm_type": "default",
    "data": "Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing."
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "alarm_type": "default",
    "data": "Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
}]
```

The javascript functions:

```
var alarmsQueue = alarms.getAlarms();

alarmsQueue.then(function(result) {

    var alarmsTypes = _.map(result, 'alarm_type');

    console.log(alarmsTypes);

});
```

The result is the following array:

```
["danger", "danger", "warning", "info", "success", "default", "danger", "default", "default"]
```

And I would like to obtain the following object from the previous:

```
{"danger": 3, "warning": 1, "info": 1, "success": 1, "default": 3}
```

What would be the best way to proceed?

Comment: Don't you mean `{"danger": 3, ...}`?

Comment: @Arg0n corrected, thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a one-liner using [`_.countBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy).

```
_.countBy(alarmsTypes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/92nwra8b/1/) JSFiddle

JavaScript

```
var alarmTypes = ["danger", "danger", "warning", "info", "success", "default", "danger", "default", "default"];

var alarmTypeCount = {};

for(var i = 0; i < alarmTypes.length; i++){
    var alarmType = alarmTypes[i];
    if(alarmTypeCount[alarmType]) {
        alarmTypeCount[alarmType]++;
    } else {
        alarmTypeCount[alarmType] = 1;
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(alarmTypeCount)); // {"danger":3,"warning":1,"info":1,"success":1,"default":3}
```

Comment: it helped understand the process better than the accepted answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't  have `["danger": 3, "warning": 1, "info": 1, "success": 1, "default": 3]`,

but you could group the key-values in an object and have:

```
[{"danger": 3}, {"warning": 1}, ....]
```

or make a unique object with key-value pairs like:

```
 {"danger": 3, "warning": 1, ....}
```

here's the solution to the second scenario using reduce method:

```
var alarmsTypes = _.reduce(result, function (ac,v) {

     if ( ac[v.alarm_type] ) {
       ac[v.alarm_type] ++;
     }else{
      ac[v.alarm_type] = 1;
     };
   return ac
   },{});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/wrj4su6b/2/)